# Prevent dependent destroy in acts_as_commentable_with_threading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, acts-as-commentable

I am using [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading).  I am using devise to allow users to deactivate their account instead of delete.  I am still using the devise destroy action to do this and so a delete request is sent.

The gem seems to delete all owned comments by the user and I want to prevent this.  I think I have found where this happens in the gem [here](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/blob/a579b92b497cbb2b5b5e8be78b760cf1c652dfa3/lib/acts_as_commentable_with_threading.rb) but I am not sure.  I've pasted the code below:

```
module ClassMethods
  def acts_as_commentable
    has_many :comment_threads, class_name: 'Comment', as: :commentable
    before_destroy { |record| record.root_comments.destroy_all }
    include Acts::CommentableWithThreading::LocalInstanceMethods
    extend Acts::CommentableWithThreading::SingletonMethods
  end
end
```

I think it all happens because of the `before_destroy` callback.  How can I prevent this from happening?